# How to get messages from queue destination?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, queue

Configure WebSocketMessageBroker

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

Connect to destination is successful

> SUBSCRIBE
>
> id:sub-0
>
> destination:/user/queue/bot

And from server side returned event of subscribe

SessionSubscribeEvent[GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=SUBSCRIBE, stompCommand=SUBSCRIBE, nativeHeaders={id=[sub-0], destination=[/user/queue/bot]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpHeartbeat=[J@2881ad6c, simpSubscriptionId=sub-0, simpSessionId=l4lyrtxo, simpDestination=/user/queue/bot}]]

which has **simpDestionation** as */user/queue/bot*

Let's try to send message to this destination

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(user, "/queue/bot", new UserResponse(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
```

where user is current **simpSessionId** from:

SessionConnectedEvent[GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT_ACK, simpConnectMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT, stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={accept-version=[1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpHeartbeat=[J@1f44ec3d, simpSessionId=l4lyrtxo}], simpSessionId=l4lyrtxo}]]

But this messages is not available in client side

Client subscribe via following code:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/bot', function (greeting) {
            console.log(greeting);
        });
```

How to get messages from queue destination ?

I tried to brainstorm, and in class SimpMessagingTemplate in Spring found following:

```
super.convertAndSend(this.destinationPrefix + user + destination, payload, headers, postProcessor);
```

It's means, that final destination is */user/[simpSessionId]/queue/bo*t or no ?

On log via VM -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE

```
2020-02-14 18:42:46.281 TRACE 20460 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler        : From client: SUBSCRIBE /queue/test id=sub-0 session=d2cjojbp
2020-02-14 18:42:46.287 DEBUG 20460 --- [nboundChannel-5] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing SUBSCRIBE /queue/test id=sub-0 session=d2cjojbp
2020-02-14 18:42:47.509 TRACE 20460 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.m.s.u.UserDestinationMessageHandler  : No active sessions for user destination: /user/d2cjojbp/queue/test
```

Comment: please, provide your websocket server side configuration and your client side connection to this websocket. This will be very heplfull to find out what's wrong

Comment: Hi, https://github.com/Rcr9/Test-WS - client side connection in resources/static/app.js

Comment: @FelipeBonfante additional information in the question added

Comment: The `UserDestinationMessageHandler` resolves the final destination using a `UserDestinationResolver` (most likely the `DefaultUserDestinationResolver`), which translates the `simpUserId` to a `sessionId`.